# PostgreSQL ST_Point

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Пытаюсь вставить в базу точку

```
INSERT INTO "my_points" ("coord_point") VALUES (ST_Point(27.53899097442627,53.902770584646525));
```

Но почему-то появляется ошибка

```
SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR: column "coord_point" is of type point but expression is of type geometry
```

Поле в таблице имеет тип POINT и вроде как ST_Point должен возвращать такой же тип, а не geometry. Почему такое происходит?

PostgreSQL 9.4, PostGIS 2.1

Comment: по-моему [это](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24486/how-to-insert-a-point-into-postgis) оч. похоже на ваш случай

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему таким вот способом:

```
INSERT INTO "my_points" ("coord_point") VALUES (POINT(27.53899097442627 53.902770584646525));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Name
>
> ST_Point — Returns an ST_Point with the given coordinate values. OGC
>   alias for ST_MakePoint.
>
> Synopsis
>
> geometry ST_Point(float x_lon, float y_lat);
>
> Description
>
> Returns an ST_Point with the given coordinate values. MM compliant
>   alias for ST_MakePoint that takes just an x and y.

[Взято отсюда](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Points.html)

Как видно ST_Point возвращает именно геометрию, вообще многое что начинается с ST_ или возвращает или получает geography/geometry.